# Android - Wait for a UI thread callback without returning from function

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm investigating making a framework to use a WebView to run arbitrary JavaScript.  It works fine.

For programmer convenience I'd like to be able to make a synchronous call invoking a bit of JavaScript, and get the result within a single function (No comments please about code execution speed.  Of course it'll be slow).

But the threading model is causing me problems. WebView makes its callbacks to the UI thread - which is nice and programmer-friendly.  But it makes trouble for me.  I'd like to be able to do this in the UI thread:

```
String four = X.invokeJavaScriptReturningString("2+2"); // result "4"
```

where the method is as follows:

```
public String invokeJavaScriptReturningString( final String javaScript) throws InterruptedException {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final String[] result = new String[1]; // Kludge - array is assignable from nested class.

    ValueCallback<String> callback = new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
            result[0] = s;
            latch.countDown();
        }
    };
    mWebView.evaluateJavascript(javaScript, callback);

    latch.await(99, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return result[0];  
}
```

But of course the callback message gets queued in the UI thread message queue, and the function blocks for 99 seconds then returns null.

Some message-based thread models have a way to work around this; something like:

```
while (!latch.await(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) {
    // Process any messages in the UI thread Looper queue.
}
```

But I can't find any way to get at the Android Looper queue.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: "Any suggestions how to solve this?" -- use an actual JavaScript engine rather than `WebView`. Rhino, JavaScriptCore, V8, SpiderMonkey, duktape, etc.

Comment: Yes, I'd considered them.  But they've all got limitations compared with the WebView environment.  And since the only issue is this minor threading inconvenience, it seems sensible to try to solve the problem as I've stated it.

Comment: "it seems sensible to try to solve the problem as I've stated it" -- IMHO, it is not. The main application thread is **not your thread**. You did not create it. You do not own it. Messing with it, or with things tightly coupled to it (e.g., its work queue) will make very unsafe assumptions about the nature of that thread.

Comment: Err - our problem is that while I'm in that function I _do_ own the UI thread. The trick of processing events from the event loop was a common one in (normally single-threaded) Symbian OS. However, if no such mechanism exists in Android, then too bad. :-(